# Configure LinkPlugin <a href class> or other attributes by the parent plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm running Django CMS 3.4.

Is it possible to set the class attribute for children LinkPlugin instances from a parent plugin ?

I was thinking it about overriding the `render` method of my parent plugin. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

I know that one can add the class attribute for a link within the link edit view. But this is tedious and problematic with layout changes, since the class attribute is then set within the data.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create a custom template and instead of simply using `{% render_plugin plugin %}` just explicitly declare the child instance markup with your chosen class.

Answer (score 1):

As @markwalker_ supposed I solved the problem by rendering the child in the parent template like this. I omitted target attributes rendering et al. for sake of simplicity.

```
{% for child in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
  {% render_plugin_block child %}
    <div>
      <a href="{{ child.get_link }}" class="button">{{ child.name }}</a>
    </div>
  {% endrender_plugin_block %}
  <!-- render_plugin must be called otherwise no frontend 
       editing possible -->
  <div style="display: none">
    {% render_plugin child %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
{% for child in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
  {% with instance as parent %}
    {% render_plugin child %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

This then gives you access to the "parent" variable in the child's template.